# over years or years-over?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Which sounds more natural:

> ... has been repeated over years ...

or

> ... has been repeated years-over ....

And in the second case, is hyphenation correct?

(The meaning should be, that this thing has been repeated many times over the span of many years.)

Comment: Both look wrong.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: Neither seems very idiomatic. "Has been repeated for years" or "Has been repeated over many years" are better to me. I'm unsure if "years-over" is at all plausible, it doesn't seem the sort of thing anyone would say.

Comment: See ["year-over-year"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/year-over-year). That's a specialized phrase, mostly for financial contexts in which you're comparing years, and is not the same as "year after year."

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "over years", and I'm not sure why other people find it strange.  It simply means "over a period of years", and [you can find multiple examples in live usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22repeated+over+years%22&biw=1740&bih=931&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBtI6vyBF5rEomBWyC-CYd7vjp4IEg%3A1650488417063&ei=YXRgYrChA6KJptQPp7GP8A4&ved=0ahUKEwjw1be-xKP3AhWihIkEHafYA-4Q4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22repeated+over+years%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ6wZYygxgsg1oAHAAeAGAAbwBiAHEBZIBAzkuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books).

Comment: Repeated over the years might seem more natural to some

Answer (score 2):

1. <strike>Repeated years over</strike> doesn't sound right.
2. **Repeated over years** is correct and quite common. (As shown by @Stangdon)
3. **Repeated over the years** seems the most idiomatic to me. (Also mentioned by @DialFrost.)

PS Google Ngrams agree.

[image]

Comment: But don't they they each imply something slightly different? "Over years" seems to stress a long length of time. "Over the years" does not so much stress time, as recognise that it has been happening over a recognised period.